# Taylor series expansion of a function in 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I was reading a [research paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7942128).  It states the following:

> $$\Phi\left(\tau_x, \tau_y\right)=\frac{k D}{2}\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2-2 \tau_x \rho \alpha-2 \tau_y \rho \beta\right) \frac{1}{\left(\rho+\frac{2 r}{D}\right)}. \hspace{1.0cm}(13)$$ $$ \frac{2 r}{D}=\left[\left(\tau_x-\alpha
>  \rho\right)^2+\left(\tau_y-\beta \rho\right)^2+(\gamma
>  \rho)^2\right]^{1 / 2} . \hspace{3cm}(14) $$
>
> We expand (14) in a Taylor series in the variables $\left(\tau_x,
>  \tau_y\right)$ up to the fourth-order, or quartic, term and use it in
> (13) to obtain $$ \begin{aligned} \Phi\left(\tau_x, \tau_y\right)= &
>  -\frac{k D}{2}\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta \tau_y\right)+\frac{k D}{4 \rho}\left[\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)-\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta
> \tau_y\right)^2\right] \pm \\ & +\frac{k D}{8 \rho^2}\left(\alpha
>  \tau_x+\beta
>  \tau_y\right)\left[\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)-2\left(\alpha
>  \tau_x+\beta \tau_y\right)^2\right] \\ & -\frac{k D}{16
>  \rho^3}\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)^2+\frac{k D}{16
>  \rho^3}\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta \tau_y\right)^2 \\ &
>  \times\left[6\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)-5\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta
>  \tau_y\right)^2\right] . \\ & +\cdots \hspace{8.5cm}(15) 
>  \end{aligned} $$
> Note that $\Phi$ in (15) may be viewed as a Taylor series expansion in
> terms of the small parameters $\left(\tau_x, \tau_y\right)$ or in
> terms of a series in the inverse powers of the large parameter $\rho$.

Can someone help me verify that  (15) is correct? Why do they have a $\pm$ sign. Also, I am doubtful about the term
$$-\frac{k D}{16
 \rho^3}\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)^2+\frac{k D}{16
 \rho^3}\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta \tau_y\right)^2 \\ 
 \times\left[6\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)-5\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta
 \tau_y\right)^2\right]$$ .
Is it missing a bracket? Is the correct form $$\left[-\frac{k D}{16
 \rho^3}\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)^2+\frac{k D}{16
 \rho^3}\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta \tau_y\right)^2 \right]\\ 
 \times\left[6\left(\tau_x^2+\tau_y^2\right)-5\left(\alpha \tau_x+\beta
 \tau_y\right)^2\right]$$

I am not very fluent in this sort of approximation. So any help in verifying the correctness would be appreciated!